# Python 'ascii' codec can't encode character with request.get

Tags: python, json, encoding, utf-8, ascii

I have a Python program which crawls data from a site and returns a json. The crawled site has the meta tag charset = ISO-8859-1. Here is the source code:

```
url = 'https://www.example.com'
source_code = requests.get(url)
plain_text = source_code.text
```

After that I am getting the information with Beautiful Soup and then creating a json. The problem is, that some symbols i.e. the `€` symbol are displayed as \u0080 or \x80 (in python) so I can't use or decode them in php. So I tried `plain_text.decode('ISO-8859-1)` and `plain_text.decode('cp1252')` so I could encode them afterwards as utf-8 but every time I get the error: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position 8496: ordinal not in range(128).

**EDIT**

the new code after @ChrisKoston suggestion using `.content` instead of `.text`

```
url = 'https://www.example.com'
source_code = requests.get(url)
plain_text = source_code.content
the_sourcecode = plain_text.decode('cp1252').encode('UTF-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(the_sourcecode, 'html.parser')
```

encoding and decoding is now possible but still the character problem.

**EDIT2**

the solution is to set it `.content.decode('cp1252')`

```
url = 'https://www.example.com'
source_code = requests.get(url)
plain_text = source_code.content.decode('cp1252')
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
```

**Special thanks to Tomalak for the solution**

Comment: Try using source_code.content instead of .text

Comment: @ChrisKoston Thank you! Now I am able to decode and encode the plain_text but sadly it does not solve the character issue. I posted the new code above.

Comment: Hint: `plain_text.decode('cp1252').encode('utf-8')` does not change the value of `plain_text`.

Comment: @Tomalak yeah you are right, i edited the source code again but still no change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must actually store the result of `decode()` somewhere because it does not modify the original variable.

Another thing:

- `decode()` turns a list of bytes into a string.
- `encode()` does the oposite, it turns a string into a list of bytes

BeautifulSoup is happy with strings; you don't need to use `encode()` at all.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.example.com'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content.decode('cp1252')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

Hint: For working with HTML you might want to look at [pyquery](https://pythonhosted.org/pyquery/) instead of BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Thank your for your quick help.  I edited the source code but the `€` character is still \x80 when I run the program

Comment: `\x80` is the character code for the Euro symbol. Don't look at the IDLE console, it displays characters this way when it wants to. Write the string to a file and look again.

Comment: this worked for the title now! thanks alot for that. the description is still not working. I´ll post the code in the question

Comment: Now everything is working. i had to replace the `.text` with `. content` there, too. Thank you so much for your help!